# ViewModelProviders.of(FragmentActivity).get(ViewModel::class.java) asking for activity instead of viewmodel in get() call

Tags: android, gradle, mvvm, kotlin, viewmodelproviders

ViewModelProviders.of(this).get() is failing for unforeseen reasons
This is being called in my main activity which inherits from FragmentActivity. I'm actually getting an error on the .get() call. The error says it's expecting an activity instead of a ViewModel which goes against the docs. I've cleared and invalidated caches. My guess is that I have a bad import or an old library version somehow

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity import android.os.Bundle import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView import com.apsoftware.urbandictionary.R

class DefinitionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPostListBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: DefinitionActivity


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.postList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DefinitionViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    } }

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.6.0'
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.20"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared

```
private lateinit var viewModel: DefinitionActivity
```

I.e., `viewModel` is an instance of a `DefinitionActivity`. It should be a `DefinitionViewModel` to match what you pass into `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 private lateinit var viewModel: DefinitionActivity
```

to

```
 private lateinit var viewModel: DefinitionViewModel
```